# is illegal in an expression for a directoryin autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

So im confused why this is a illegal expression
its saying Z:\ is it

```
#SingleInstance,Force

If Exist Z:\
    Goto BackupStart
else 
Return 

BackupStart:
Msgbox,,Test,Test
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use either [If[Not]Exist](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExist.htm) (deprecated)

```
IfExist Z:\
```

or  the [FileExist function](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileExist.htm)

```
If FileExist("Z:\")
```

to check for the existence of a file, folder or drive.